# Laravel not finding class

Tags: laravel

I have a project I'm working on right now, in which I created a database to hold some info. I've already created a view and a controller where I can add data to the DB and it works. But for some reason when I try to use on a view to list my information it won't work.

Here's my model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['descricption','image'];
}
```

And these are the first few lines of my view which laravel point to error:

```php
@php

use\app\Banner;
$banner = new Banner;
$banners = Banner::all();

@endphp
```

Whenever I try to open this view, I get the "Class 'app\Banner' not found" error. What am I doing wrong? Since it worked to add data to the database before, and I did remember of putting the use\app\Banner;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace is `App` not `app`. Always act like case sensitivity matters and you won't have these problems.

```
use App\Banner;
```

Side Note: you can pass this data to your view instead of having to do this query in your view.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was such a trivial error.